# angularjs create/export html view as pdf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to create a modal window, in this window I have some information, some tables and text areas, is it possible to create an .pdf from this .html modal view?

I looked into FileSaver, but this only works well for downloading tables, what I want is almost like a printscreen of the modal window.

Comment: you can use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: How can I download the canvas instead of displaying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

covert html to canvas using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and then use jsPdf to convert to pdf. here is example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/p4s5k59s/5/)

like this

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
<button id="download">Download Pdf</button>

html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {         
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
            'image/png');              
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }
});
```

Comment: that is perfect. I think I can apply this to my project, thanks